# Dropdown value not populating in php on change

Tags: php

I want to pass Drop Down value to php, i am new to PHP please help

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script>

    function displayVals() {
      var singleValues = $("#account").val();

      $("p").html("<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues);
    }
</script>
 <select id="account" name="account">
    <option value="1">Tes1</option>
    <option value="2">Tes2</option>
  </select>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$account = $_get['account']; 

echo $account;  

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I want to pass Drop Down value to php, i am new to PHP please help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo $_POST['account'];
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <select id="account" name="account">
        <option value="1">Tes1</option>
        <option value="2">Tes2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

You need to make a form

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you,

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['save'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT Business_Unit, COUNT(Joining_Month) AS 'A' FROM jl WHERE Business_Unit = '".$_REQUEST['opt']."' GROUP BY Business_Unit";

        // Here is your sql query
        echo $sql;exit();
    }
?>
```

Yor HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="opt">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="save" />
</form>
```

Given simple working demo to fulfill your requirement. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Basically i want to pass variable in mysql WHERE clause for example ($sql="SELECT Business_Unit, COUNT(Joining_Month) AS 'A' FROM jl WHERE Business_Unit = '$POST_[account]' GROUP BY Business_Unit";)

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Hey @Patil, check out updated answer. hope you will like my stuff,,!

Comment: Downvoted this answer, because the PHP code contains an SQL injection. The $_REQUEST['opt'] must be escaped before concatenating it with an SQL statement.